# Can I use Registry_Key to set Start Menu 'Expand' button to always on

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The button at the top left of the Start Menu Panel that expands the folder icons over the top of the 'All Apps' list.

I would like this button to be set to always on, so that it always covers the 'all apps' list.

Is this possible?  And if so what registry key needs to be set?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, no, that isn't possible.

For what it's worth, many people want to hide the **All Apps** list by default, and Microsoft has taken action based upon their feedback.  Starting with the upcoming Windows 10 Creators Update (build 14942 or newer), the option will be available to modify your settings in order to **Hide app list in Start menu**.  Once you enable that feature, when you click on Start on the upper-left you will have the option to choose between **Expand**, **Pinned Tiles** view, and the **All Apps** view.

[image: Start Menu Pinned Tiles View]

([Source](http://pureinfotech.com/hide-app-list-start-menu-windows-10/))

Comment: Ok, Cool.  I'll look out for that. Thanks for swift reply